# How to implement MMS functionality in 3.0 sdk?

Tags: iphone

Can we implement MMS functionality in our application how it possble.can you give me idea about that?

Comment: did you actually do a search on SO before asking? -.-

Comment: @Till, why so aggressively demanding?

Comment: @Alex because there are about 20 entries within SO referring to that very same question.

Comment: @Till, you could always flag it to be closed, if it bothers you.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use MMS.